# Recorrer arreglo java eficientemente

Tags: java, array, loops

Últimamente he querido empezar a pensar más que en soluciones, en ser eficaz al momento de programar. Y es por ello que me topo con la siguiente duda, y tal como dice el título es:

**¿Cuál es la manera más eficiente de recorrer un arreglo en Java?**

Y más que importar el método, es el por qué es la mejor forma, ya que así puedo aplicar estos conocimientos en otros casos distintos.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Una mejor forma no existe, pero hay distintas formas para sus casos de uso. Como el tamaño de una arreglo no cambia en Java después de haber sido creado, la forma clasica es por una iteración sobre los indices:

```
// ejemplo de arreglo
Object[] arreglo = new Object[10];
//...
for (int i = 0; i < arreglo.length; i++){
    // aqui se puede referir al objeto con arreglo[i];
}
```

Este método usa un bucle simple con un primitivo como indice así no es muy costoso, y se usa cuando es necesario de saber el indice junto con el objeto del arreglo.

Otra forma si no hay importancia cuantos elementos existen en el arreglo o no se necesita referencia al indice es:

```
for (Object o : arreglo){
    // en cada iteración "o" se refiere a un objeto del arreglo para todos objetos en el arreglo
}
```

Ambas formas necesitan pocos recursos y hay que recordar que no tiene mucho sentido en Java de sobrepensar la optimisación de código, porque se invertió una tremenda inteligencia de optimizar la ejecución del bytecode en la maquina virtual desde el JIT-compilador (just in time).

Solamente hay que recordar que es recomendable en contexto de rendimiento de evitar funciones muy altas para casos simples si se quiere minimizar el cabezero. El proximo ejemplo usa más recursos, porque involucra instar varios objetos extra, que siempre significa uso de más recursos en tiempo de ejecución y memoria:

```
Iterator i = Arrays.asList(arreglo).iterator();
while(i.hasNext()){
    // trabajar con Objeto o = i.next()
}
```

Comment: Entiendo lo que me dices acerca de la maquina virtual. Sin embargo entiendo que dichos métodos, acceden a métodos dentro de la maquina virtual, y hay loops que entiendo que ocupan mas y otros menos métodos, y entre mas nativo, sera mas rápido. Se entiende que en arreglos pequeños no se ve la diferencia, pero los consulto justamente para grandes volúmenes de datos que están alojados en arreglos y deben ser procesados

Comment: el mas eficiente llevado a bytecodes debería ser el `for(;;)`, trabaja con tipos primitivos, no hace asignaciones de mas, no carga clases adicionales, ... Puedes ver esta [pregunta interesante](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6792305/identify-loops-in-java-byte-code)

Comment: @JoséMiguelSepulveda de verdad, no te rompe la cabeza exageradamente por mejoras de performancia más alla de evitar instar objetos. En muchos tests en casos reales me di cuenta que los diseñadores de las JCM hiecieron un estupendo trabajo en las optimisaciones, y uno al fin ni puede saber si un código realmente es más performante si uno no hace pruebas en muchas maquinas físicas distintas. Preferir primitivos si sirve, pero pasado a eso, cuenta iteraciónes no más.

Comment: @ArieCwHat claro, porque reducir 0.001 ms en un for va a brindar el mejor performance a mi aplicación que hace miles de operaciones adicionales a ciclos for (que son optimizados luego por el JIT). Como bien dijo Donald Knuth: "la optimización prematura es la causa de todos los males"

Comment: @Luiggi Mendoza Es cierto que preocuparse demasiado por el rendimiento podría limitar las opciones de diseño y buenas prácticas, pero no hacerlo a su tiempo produce software mediocre y la experiencia de los usuarios a veces llega a ser afectada por no considerar ciertos aspectos. Como dijo Donald Knutt: "La optimización prematura"... esto no quiere decir que en algún momento no debas hacer mejoras del rendimiento o que si tienes la oportunidad de hacer las cosas de manera óptima no las hagas. No es cosa de Milisegundos, sino de usar bien los recursos que tienes.

Comment: Hay una diferencia entre optimisacion prematura y KISS. Un buen desarrollador sabe que son maneras performantes y que no son, Hacer código más entendible para novatos por ejemplo no debe ser una excusa para botar recursos. En mi punto de vista la optimisacion prematura se refiere más a decisiones de arquitectura que limitan la mantenibilidad después. Muchos factores impactan en eso, como portablidad, compatibilidad etc. En el contexto de Java, lo que fue más rapido ayer puede ser más lento despues de la proxima actualisación de la JVM. Pienso que moderación y criterio son las palabras claves.

Comment: @Stefan Estoy de acuerdo contigo, depende mucho del contexto. Hay casos en los que la optimización es muy importante, otros que simplemente es mejor un buen diseño. :P Recientemente tenía que [generar un HeatMap](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/53314/4617), en estas situaciones el rendimiento es muy importante.

Comment: Claro que sí, programación de sistemas, UI y juegos tipicamente viven de un máximo de rendimiento.

Answer (score 5):

Desde java 8 puedes utilizar programacion funcional con expresiones Lambdas

Intente hacer el codigo lo mas legible posible.

```
//declaramos e inicializamos el arreglo de numeros int.
int [] arreglo = {5,7,8,3,12,45,95,2,56,789,123,456,789,14,1,3,45,84,984};

//for normal indicamos una variable i la que almacenara el indice del arreglo el cual vamos a iterar y se incrementara en uno.
for(int i=0;i<arreglo.length ; i++)
{
    System.out.println(arreglo[i]);
}

//utilizamos un for-each para escribir menos codigo, indicando el tipo de dato,una variable pivote luego dos puntos (:) y finalmente el arreglo que vamos a recorrer 
for(int pivote : arreglo)
{
    System.out.println(pivote);
}

//utilizamos Java 8 con Lambdas , primero convertimos nuestro arreglo a una lista con el metodo Arrays.asList luego utilizamos el metodo foreach de las colecciones Java el cual nos pide un parametro Consumer.
Arrays.asList(arreglo).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Espero te sirva
Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Si te refieres a recorrer un array por completo (lo que sería leer todos sus elementos) realmente no creo que se pueda aplicar ninguna optimización(o esta ser inapreciable) más allá de la legibilidad de una forma u otra, esto es debido a que el compilador terminará haciendo la conversión del mismo.

Te dejo esta pregunta en la versión inglesa,con respuesta más completas por si te puede servir:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006395/fastest-way-to-iterate-an-array-in-java-loop-variable-vs-enhanced-for-statement

Answer (score -2):

//Declaramos la variable
int []array=new int[100];

```
     //recorremos hasta el limite del array 
       
        for (i=0;i<array.length;i++) {//inicia el bucle
           
         
           // va imprimiendo de forma constatnte hasta que termina el reccorido
           System.out.println("i"+i);
        
           
       }//cierra el bucle
```